# Angular 2 app slow initial load because of added external third party js libs to angular-cli.json

Tags: javascript, performance, angular, angular-cli, single-page-application

I have gone through angular cli and other links on how to add external js files to the project so finally added it to scripts tag in angular-cli.json.

I am using yFiles graphing library. I have added 10 already minified js files to scripts array in angular-cli.json.

After doing

```
ng build --aot --prod
```

the final build has **scripts.bundle.js** of size >4MB which makes my app to **load slowly/slow initial rendering**  only because of this file. Any help would be great on how to load these files after showing the initial screen...But what if i want to use these libraries on my initial screen only?

I am right now having a loading screen, which is there for around 15-18 secs on first load before going into my application.

My first screen itself uses these libs.

Any help or workarounds would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: So, how big are the 10 scripts that you added? Do they add up to less than 4MB? 

Also, you should probably add the un-minified versions, because the build will try to minify them again.

Comment: they add upto exactly 4.5 MB!! Since they are already minified its not getting minified anymore!!  @GreyBeardedGeek

Answer (score 0):

If you use the un-minified versions of those scripts, you *may* find that Angular minimizes them better, but I wouldn't expect too much.

The real problem is that your adding 4Mb of JavaScript. You should probably review that, and see if you really need all of it, or if you can get rid of some.